# How to get answer from two checked checkboxes in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have these pages:

secondpage.php

```html
<center>
    <a href="fourthpage.php">Go back</a>
    <form action="fourthpage.php" method="POST">
        <select name="what" class="what" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter what are you paying for ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose what you are paying for</option>
            <option>Something</option>
            <option>Something</option>
            <option>Something</option>
            <option>Something</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button>other...</button>
        <br><br>
        <label for="price">Type the price</label>
        <br>
        <input id="amount" name="price" placeholder="&#8364" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the price ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /   type="number">
        <br><br>
        <label for="payment">Who has to pay for it:</label>
        <br>
        <label for="everybody">Everybody</label>
        <input name="check_list[]" class="everybody" type="checkbox"  value="everybody" onclick="ckChange(this)" required>
        &nbsp&nbsp
        <label for="John">John</label>
        <input name="check_list[]" class="John" type="checkbox"  value="John" required>
        &nbsp&nbsp
        <label for="Peter">Peter</label>
        <input name="check_list[]" class="denis" type="checkbox"  value="Peter" required>
        &nbsp&nbsp
        <label for="Ferrari">Ferrari</label>
        <input name="check_list[]" class="Ferrari" type="checkbox"  value="Ferrari" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">
    </form>
</center>
```

fourthpage.php

```html
<table>
      <center><h1>John</h1></center>
        <tr><td>WHO </td><td>WHAT </td><td>HOW MUCH</td><td>MY DEBT</td><td>TOTAL DEBT</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="d"><?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
                          if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
                         // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
                          foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
                          echo $selected."</br>";
                          }}} ?></td>
           <td class="r"><?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $_POST["what"];} ; ?></td>

           <td class="a"><?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $_POST["price"];} ; ?></td>

           <td class="debt"><?php  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
                          if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
                         // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
                          foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
                           if ($selected == 'everybody'){ echo $_POST["price"]/4;}
                           elseif ($selected == 'John' || 'Peter' || 'Ferrari'){ echo $_POST["price"]/2;}
                           elseif ($selected == 'John' && $selected == 'Peter') { echo $_POST["price"]/3;} ;
                          }}}?> </td></tr>
<td class="total"><?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ;} ; ?></td></tr>

</table>
<button onClick="location.reload();location.href='secondpage.php'">ADD</button> <button>PAY</button></center>
```

and javascript

```js
function ckChange(el) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(el.name);
  if (el.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].disabled = ckName[i] !== el;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].disabled = false
    }
  }

}

$(function(){

    var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');

    requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){

        if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
            requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
        }

        else {
            requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });

});
```

When i try to get the answer of 2 checked checkboxes like

```
elseif ($selected == 'John' && $selected == 'Peter') { echo $_POST["price"]/3;}
```

it doesn't give me the right answer. I don't get the price divided by 3. For example: i chose the price 15 and under debt should be 15/3 = 5. Instead of 5  i get 7.5 7.5. Any solutions?

Comment: you mean replace them? like: elseif ($selected == 'Jacopo' && $selected == 'Denis') { echo $_POST["price"]/3;}
                           elseif ($selected == 'Jacopo' || $selected == 'Denis' || $selected == 'Angus'){ echo $_POST["price"]/2;}
                            ;

Comment: Actually, you're doing a `foreach` so this can never be true `elseif ($selected == 'Jacopo' && $selected == 'Denis')`

Comment: what can you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem not just in

`elseif ($selected == 'Jacopo' && 'Denis' && 'Angus'){ echo $_POST["price"]/2;}`

So first you want to know that this line must wrote like this.

`elseif ($selected == 'Jacopo' || $selected == 'Denis' || $selected == 'Angus'){ echo $_POST["price"]/2;}`

And Second you don't want to use another foreach. we want to make sure that the elements you're looking for inside the `check_list` array, So you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

This is your final code.

```
<td class="debt"><?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
        if (in_array('everybody', $_POST['check_list'])){ echo $_POST["price"]/4;}
        elseif (in_array('Jacopo', $_POST['check_list']) && in_array('Denis', $_POST['check_list'])) { echo $_POST["price"]/3;}
        elseif (in_array('Jacopo', $_POST['check_list']) || in_array('Denis', $_POST['check_list']) || in_array('Angus', $_POST['check_list'])){ echo $_POST["price"]/2;}
    }
}
?></td>
```

I hope everything is clear and i hope i helped you.

Comment: this one gives me an error: Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in

Comment: in first `elseif` i put a break for another try, remove it and the code will work 100%.

Comment: @McCormick i'm waiting your next reply, and i will be happy to help you more.

Comment: @McCormick you're welcome, its a pleasure to help you :) i hope my answer is clear to understand not just worked, if you want more explanation just ask and i will be happy to help you more :)

Comment: God Bless You) Well actually i will have questions later but let me first try a little bit harder if i will stuck then i will come back to you)) Really thank you a lot it was not just worked but i understood where was the mistake)

Comment: @McCormick i'm waiting you, whatever you want just ask i will be so glad and happy to help you :)

Comment: I added another td = total debt i want to do so: the data in my debt appear with checkbox and when checkbox checked reduce total debt when uncheck return back. Is it possible?)

Comment: @McCormick sorry i'm late, but try it, and tell me if there is any problem.

Comment: Try what?) i don't see anything)

Comment: @McCormick i didn't put anything, try to do it in your own, if you have any problem i will try to help you :)

Comment: Mohammed May i ask your help again ? i'm kinda stuck again. Can you send me your email ? I want to send you my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @McCormick ask it in the website and i will help you again, check my profile i added my email you can contact me there, and sorry i'm late.

Comment: i have sent you an email. Please check it when you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it like this (correct me if not):

- if "everybody" was checked, case 1
- if ALL THREE (respectively TWO) boxes with names are checked, cases 2 or 3
- any other combination will be ignored

In this case you must ensure, that $_POST['check_list'] has all the required items checked and nothing more. Please consider the following example:

```
// to play around with...
$_POST['check_list'] = ['everybody', 'Jacopo', 'Denis'];

$case1 = ['everybody'];
$case2 = ['Jacopo', 'Denis', 'Angus'];
$case3 = ['Jacopo', 'Denis'];

$result1 = array_intersect($_POST['check_list'], $case1);
$result2 = array_intersect($_POST['check_list'], $case2);
$result3 = array_intersect($_POST['check_list'], $case3);

if (count($case1) == count($result1)) {
    echo 'case 1';
}
elseif (count($case2) == count($result2)) {
    echo 'case 2';
}
elseif (count($case3) == count($result3)) {
    echo 'case 3';
}
```

The array_intersect will compare all arrays to find things in common. Anything that is not in any of the other arrays will be removed. Set theory.

edit: fixed typos

Comment: `$case1 = ['everybody');` i think you forgot to close the the square brackets.

Comment: thx, fixed it. In fact it was a mixup (I'm still used to "array" instead of then new notation with square brackes)